# Getting ENOENT: no such file or directory, open... error when trying to move App.js/index.js files into subfolders inside /src folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

So I've basically created three folders inside my React.js `./src`folder named `browser`, `server` and `shared` on VScode. However, moving for example the index.js file or the main App.js file within it leads to this very annoying error showing up on the browser:

```
./src/index.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'I:\React apps\mywebsite\src\index.js'
```

I've had problems with this in my actual project so I decided to create a fresh new project and still I get this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem after delete of a Component file that was replaced by a new one from a merge : impossible to take the new one into account.

Diagnostic :
Since the path to the old file is displayed, you have to find out where it's kept

```
grep -r "path/to/DeletedComponent.js" ./*
```

Found occurences in : `./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/someHash.json`

Turns out babel wasn't detecting move/replacement of the file.

I did :

```
mv node_modules/.cache node_modules/.cacheBackup
```

Then

```
npm start
```

cache was recreated and new component was taken into account

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove localhost8000
2. Try restarting from Console..
3. Go back to the folder you was working on..
   Re run it using **npm start**

I had same issue but the above instructions helped me solve the issue.